# How to do end to end testing better against a distributed system using a github PR workflow?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, github, e2e-testing

My team uses an internal e2e testing framework to test that everything from the http request to the http response is working as expected.

How these tests work is very complicated and flaky due to the nature of a distributed architecture across multiple geographies in AWS.

A big problem we have is that when we merge a feature PR into one of our many micro-services/lambdas that impact the response/behaviour of an endpoint, our e2e tests fail.

How we deal with this is by accepting that the e2e Jenkins job will be red temporarily until someone gets an e2e PR merged that updates/adds a test/s.

Because of the acceptance of the e2e job being red "temporarily", it leads to other changes that may or may not contain bugs slipping in.

The other problem is that we don't allow PRs to be merged if the build is failing (which is great), but if the e2e tests fail due to a change in a different service, the person fixing the e2e tests for the feature they are working on will need to fix the other failures in the same PR.

So my question is, what can my team do to fix this problem?

I want us to keep the e2e tests as they are very useful, but they're prone to be neglected for the reasons above.

Could we somehow tie the e2e tests repo to each feature branch so that when someone pushes code to a branch, a feature branch with the same name on our e2e test service runs against it and blocks the PR until they update the e2e tests?

- This would need the e2e test repo to somehow be linked so that code changes there appear in the feature PR for the relevant service/lambda. Not sure if this possible.

Any advice/examples on how to do e2e testing using the github workflow for a distributed micro-services/lambda architecture in AWS would be extremely appreciated.

Also, I would find it hard to believe my team is the only one with this problem. So maybe this will help others.

Comment: Let's use separation of concerns and remove water from this question. Github and pull requests don't relate to end to end testing, so lots of redundant information can be removed from this question.

Answer (score 6):

A common test strategy you could adopt for e2e testing is to split their execution:

- for Pull Request: isolate some fast and non flaky e2e test and include them in your main pipeline
- for master branch (or release branch depending on your strategy): isolate some more non flaky e2e test that takes longer. execute them along with the e2e test that are executed with PR
- schedule a job to execute all e2e tests on a daily basis or twice a day for instance

Regarding your issue of e2e tests being red the time it gets updated, I would suggest to change your delivery strategy:

- You could prevent merging of the feature branch until the e2e tests pass on the feature branch. You could for instance require that the e2e tests would be run at least once even if a job is triggered manually and confirmation of execution success has to be done by email before allowing the merge
- You could change your branching strategy. For instance you would have a development branch, a stabilization branch and a release branch. You could execute more or less e2e tests depending on the branch and accept that the dev branch becomes red more often than the stabilization one

There is in fact no perfect solution for e2e test but I hope I gave you some ideas

PS: Is you internal testing framework built with Selenium? If so I would recommend to use a Selenium Grid solution like zalenium https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/

Also give a try to https://playwright.dev/ this framework's goal is to create reliable tests :D It works with events. you don't need to put sleep functions everywhere